# gpu regularly stops working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu

I've been having trouble with ubuntu and my gpu stopping working together periodically. I primarily use my gpu with darktable and it usually works perfectly but I periodically get notifications when launching darktable that a gpu isn't available and processing really slows up(I also have had darktable slow down after reopening the computer with darktable open and the gpu options are greyed out in darktable's settings). This at least usually happens after closing up my laptop but I'm not 100% sure it hasn't happened after just closing darktable but keeping the computer open. So far the only way I've found to get the gpu going again is to reboot the computer. I'm pretty certain this is a system rather than darktable issue as I also have davinci resolve installed which only launches with a functional gpu and it won't launch when darktable isn't able to use the gpu(davinci resolve launches properly when darktable can use the gpu). The gpu I'm using is a geforce rtx 3050 mobile using nvidia driver metapackage from navidia-driver-510. This is my first time getting a gpu up and running so I may well have done something wrong in the setup.

Any ideas on how to get my gpu working properly consistently? Thanks

Comment: Did you get your Nvidia drivers from the standard repositories (restricted), or from somewhere else?  510 is available from the standard repos. Drivers from elsewhere lack the "glue" code to recompile the module when a new kernel is installed.

Comment: I think I installed it from the repositories, unfortunately I can't look through my terminal history as I may have destroyed my ubuntu install when I tried to change which nvidia driver I was using to see if that would help and when I restarted the computer I got stuck on a black screen with some text that I get stuck on if I do a hard shutdown and try to boot into either normal or recovery mode(text in next post due to characters limit)

Comment: [   0.366457] pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PI0 log size 0 is invalid
 - Gave up waiting for root file system deice. Common problems:
   - Check rootdelay: (did the system wait long enought?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules: ls /dev)
ALERT! VVID=98D64C8B-58F0-4731-85CB-3AF3FDED657 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)